# Wrong mesh collider when import FBX from Blender to Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, blender

I'm trying to import models from blender to Unity, but the mesh colliders are wrong when they are adding them to an object in Unity.

Here are my steps:

1. Imported new asset.
2. Checked "Generate colliders".

[image: options]

3. Added mesh collider and the result is:

[image: mesh from Blender]

Comment: Is the convex option checked?

Comment: tried both ways.

Comment: Did you apply your transformation inside Blender ?

Answer (score 0):

Don't generate the collider when you import the mesh, uncheck the box.
You can later add in the inspector a mesh collider component and set it to convex, but this would be the same result you already have. You can uncheck convex, then unity tries to use your current geometry. But if the vertex count is to hight, unity won't apply a collider because the physic system only supports a certain amount of geometry.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRNCz.png)

you can also duplicate your object in blender and add a decimate modifier and play around with the Ratio or create your own geometry around your object with vertex snapping or any workflow you like, just keep the collider geometry as simple as possible.
Then you can set that mesh in the mesh collider component as mesh source and have a nice and proper collider.